# How come mathematicians published in Annals of Eugenics?

Tags: soft-question, ho.history-overview

I was surprised to see that On the construction of balanced incomplete block designs by [Raj Chandra Bose](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raj_Chandra_Bose) was published (in 1939) in a journal named Annals of Eugenics (see [here](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.1469-1809.1939.tb02219.x)) (published between 1925 and 1954).

I double checked and it [seems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annals_of_Eugenics) that the journal was indeed focused on eugenics and the article does not relate to eugenics or genetics in any way. So why would a mathematician decide to publish in such a journal and why was the article accepted?

It appears that there are also [other](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.1469-1809.1937.tb02160.x) mathematics articles published in the same journal.

Comment: Various statisticians worked on block designs in the early days, since they were relevant to design of experiments, eg agricultural.

Comment: Just looking at the same issue of this journal, there's another mathematical paper ("*solution to a geometrical problem in probability*") not obviously related to the title of the journal, and also a paper ("*equilibrium between mutation and random extinction*") with a clear applied mathematics contents, and seems (at first sight) to fit in "evolutionary biology". I'm not able here to summarize the scope of this journal, but at least this does not seem like an isolated case. A better answer could be made if the editorial board at that time (including affiliations) were made available.

Comment: This is just a hypothesis, but mathematicians, depending on the context, can have pressure to produce "useful" mathematics. In practice, this can lead some to publish  quite theoretical papers in journals that claim themselves as clearly applied (but can be happy to have such theoretical papers).

Comment: Future generations may similarly ask "How come that mathematicians of late 20 century were awarded Nobel prizes in economy?"

Comment: It is mistaken to think balanced incomplete block designs have nothing to do with eugenics or genetics. Genetics is a science that relies on statistics. A major discipline within the broader discipline of statistics is the design of experiments. The most prominent among founders of the theory of design of experiments is also one of the three major founders of the science of population genetics: Ronald Fisher. He was very active in eugenics, and he cannot be avoided if one studies the theory of statistics. And a balanced incomplete block design is prominent among designs of experiments.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Eugenics and agriculture were two areas of application that motivated much of early 20th century statistics. The paper was a continuation of research on the use of Latin squares in experimental design for those areas. It says so explicitly on the second page:

> It was, however, only about [1925] that the importance of
>   combinatorial problems, for the proper designing of biological
>   experiments, began to be understood, mainly through the work of Prof.
>   R. A. Fisher and his associates.

At the time, [Fisher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ronald_Fisher#University_College_London,_1933%E2%80%9339) was head of the Department of Eugenics at University College London.

Comment: Maybe more relevantly, Fisher was the lead editor of the *Annals of Eugenics* at the time. See also [here](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/j.1469-1809.2010.00611.x) for more history.

Answer (score 28):

One should note that in the pre-WWII period eugenics was not the dirty word that it became later. Actually it was a popular notion across the world, including in countries like the United States. The division of humanity into races and the idea that humanity could (and should) be improved by selective breeding was mainstream. Statistics was one of the enabling scientific disciplines and few mathematicians/statisticians of the time would have had moral qualms about publishing in the Annals of Eugenics.

Comment: Also worth noting that the journal in question continues to be published bimonthly to this day, though its [name was changed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annals_of_Human_Genetics) in 1954.

Comment: I'm not sure about "*few... would have had morel qualms...*". I guess there was a significant opposition to eugenics based on religious grounds (e.g. from the Catholic Church).

Comment: Fisher was Catholic.

Comment: Sure but this does not contradict what I said. Catholicism is not a unified way of thinking. (And "Catholic Church" rather means from Vatican than from catholics individually.) Nevertheless what I found so far about this opposition was quite vague and I'm curious to learn more about it.

Comment: The reasons eugenics is seen as a dirty word—a rather euphemistic way to put it—is directly tied to its historic popularity in the US and elsewhere. In particular, American eugenicists were an inspiration to the nazis. It does a disservice to history to elide these connections and present the history of eugenics as disconnected from the atrocities that led it to fall out of favor.

Comment: @ycor G.K. Chesteron's "Eugenics and other Evils" was [published in 1922](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Eugenics_and_other_Evils) the same year he was received into the Catholic Church. It doesn't contain Catholic doctrine as such, but a synthesis of social teaching (and common sense) against the Eugenicist wave engulfing England pre-WWII.

Comment: Michael Chrichton wrote a fascinating article about this: [**Why Politicized Science is Dangerous**](http://www.michaelcrichton.com/why-politicized-science-is-dangerous/).

Comment: @KamerynWilliams _The reasons eugenics is seen as a dirty word—a rather euphemistic way to put it—is directly tied to its historic popularity in the US and elsewhere._ - I don't understand this comment.  The "historic popularity" is why many people still know the word eugenics, but I would say the reason it became a dirty word is because of our knowledge of the practices of eugenicists (both in the US and in Europe).

Comment: The reason eugenics became a dirty word is not a simple story, but the fact that the Nazis showed us that it can lead to catastrophe played a big part. But even that took years to properly sink in -- note how the journal kept its name for 9 years after the end of WWII. Changes in public perceptions of a movement over decades don't always have explanations that are both simple and true.

Comment: @KamerynWilliams "*present the history of eugenics as disconnected*..." There was no attempt to present the history of eugenics. This is a focussed question on a precise link at a precise time. An attempt to present this history and notably the nazi aspect would (a) be of little help to the question (b) shade the question, as it's much more important (c) probably generate a lengthy discussion, just because it can't be summarized in a few lines, completely off-topic. So I approve the OP's choice to remain focussed. Let's refer to Wikip. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eugenics) for background.

Comment: @JLRishe Also also worth noting that the word "bimonthly" should never be used because nobody knows whether it means twice a month or every other month.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I agree completely, but that's the term that's used on the Wikipedia page.

Comment: One American eugenecist who was a professor of medicine who died in 1938 (before WWII by five years after Hitler came to power) was Charles Dight, a professor of medicine who wrote a fan letter to Adolf Hitler, to which Hitler replied.

Answer (score 3):

The zbMATH journal profile https://zbmath.org/serials/?q=se%3A00009697 has 137 reviews for documents from this journal indexed in old Jahrbuch and Zentralblatt issues, of overall 49 mathematicians. Apart from Fisher's own contributions, Bose's paper on block designs *Bose, R. C.*, [**On the construction of balanced incomplete block designs**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1111/j.1469-1809.1939.tb02219.x), Ann. Eugenics 9, 353-399 (1939). [ZBL0023.00102](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0023.00102). mentioned in the question might have been the most influential (at least, it is the one most frequently cited in subsequent reviews).